# Return file handles opened with with open?

Tags: python, with-statement

I'm creating software where I want to accept compressed files. Since files are read/written everywhere, I created a utility function for opening files, that handles opening/closing for me, for some compressed filetypes.

Example code:

```
def return_file_handle(input_file, open_mode="r"):
    """ Handles compressed and uncompressed files. Accepts open modes r/w/w+ """

    if input_file.endswith(".gz")
        with gzip.open(input_file, open_mode) as gzipped_file_handle:
            return gzipped_file_handle
```

The problem is, when using this code, the file handle seems to close when the function returns. I it possible to do what I want with `with open` or do I need to handle closing myself?

Add this to the code above to get a minimal non-working example:

```
for line in return_file_handle(input_bed, "rb"):
    print line
```

Create a gzipped textfile with:

```
echo "hei\nder!" | gzip - > test.gz
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_bed_against_blacklist.py", line 26, in <module>
    check_bed_against_blacklist("test.gz", "bla")
  File "check_bed_against_blacklist.py", line 15, in check_bed_against_blacklist
    for line in return_file_handle(input_bed, "r"):
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try it as a generator:

```
def return_file_handle(input_file, open_mode="r"):
    """
    Handles compressed and uncompressed files. Accepts open modes r/w/w+
    """
    # compressed
    if input_file.endswith(".gz"):
        with gzip.open(input_file, open_mode) as gzipped_file_handle:
            yield gzipped_file_handle
    else:
        with open(input_file, open_mode) as normal_fh:
            yield normal_fh
```

When you call it:

```
for line in return_file_handle("file.gz"):
    print(line.read())
```

Or composing a generator using [python's new `yield from` syntax:](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator)

```
def each_line(fh):
    for l in fh:
        yield from l
```

And calling it:

```
for each in each_line(return_file_handle(fh)):
    print(each)
```

with the file cleanly closing at the end of the for loop.

Comment: That's cool. I didn't realize how easy generators were in python. I like this answer the best since it closes the file for you once you're done reading it.

Comment: Careful- this might not be doing what you think.  The "return_file_handle" returns a generator to a file, NOT to the lines, so the for loop as written only runs once.  Meaning if you want to process it line-by-line:
for file in return_file_handle("file.gz"):
    for line in file.readlines():
        print line

Answer (score 4):

The best way I can think of is passing a function as parameter which accept opened fd:

```
def work(fd):
    for line in fd:
        print line

def work_with_file_handle(input_file, func, open_mode="r"):
   if input_file.endswith(".gz")
       with gzip.open(input_file, open_mode) as gzipped_file_handle:
           func(gzipped_file_handle)

work_with_file_handle('xxx.gz', work)
```

Answer (score 3):

Avoid with, if you want to return the file_handle. Because file_handle will be automatically closed when with block is finished executing.

Following code is what you should be using:

```
import gzip
def return_file_handle(input_file, open_mode="rb"):
    if input_file.endswith(".gz"):
        gzipped_file_handle = gzip.open(input_file, open_mode)
        return gzipped_file_handle

for line in return_file_handle('file.txt.gz', "r"):
    print line
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, [I don't think it is automatically closed without a `with` in pypy](https://www.pypy.org/compat.html#refcounting-del-and-resource-use). In CPython, that should be fine, though.

Answer (score 2):

The style you are using to open the file automatically closes it at the end of the block. That's the whole point of the `with` block style of opening files.

What you want to do is:

```
gzipped_file_handle = gzip.open(input_file, open_mode)
return gzipped_file_handle
```

**NOTICE**: You'll just have to be careful to remember to close the file after your call to this function.

Answer (score 2):

I would use another context manager

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def return_file_handle(input_file, open_mode="r"):
    """ Handles compressed and uncompressed files. Accepts open modes r/w/w+ """

    if input_file.endswith(".gz")
        with gzip.open(input_file, open_mode) as gzipped_file_handle:
            yield gzipped_file_handle
    else:
        with open(input_file, open_mode) as normal_file:
            yield normal_file
    # Your file will be closed after this


with return_file_handle(file_name, mode) as f:
     pass
```