# Writing csv.open as a function in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm almost a complete newbie in Python, so my question is very basic and probably naive.

I'm trying to include a csv.reader function into a custom function, because I think I might need to read several types of csv-like texts with various delimiters and quote chars and would like to quickly specify these parameters.

Here's the code I'm trying to do it with.

```
import csv

def openFile(inputPath, newline='', delimiter=',', quotechar='"'):
    with open(inputPath, newline='') as csvfile:
        openedFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter, quotechar)
    return openedFile

inputPath = "unit_structure.csv"
ff = openFile(inputPath, delimiter=';')
print (ff)
```

I get the following errors

- on the line "openedFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter, quotechar)" an error stating "expected at most 2 arguments, got 3". I've got this line of code from here https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html and it had 3 arguments there. I don't understand why it began giving an error after I've turned it into the function.
- on the line "with open(inputPath, newline) as csvfile:" an error stating "Must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode and at most one plus". This one I don't understand at all.

So I have three general questions.

1. First and foremost. Am I trying to do a correct thing, in general? I'm not sure that coding the function this way is efficient. "csv.reader" as already a function. Maybe I should just use "with open..." every time?
2. I don't understand why I get these errors. Maybe my understanding of the code structure is wrong? I think that line "with open" is a command to open a file at a specified address, "openedFile = csv.reader(...)" specifies it as a csv and then "return openedFile" returns a comma-delimited text itself. I suspect I might be wrong in this interpretation and this's why I don't understand where those error messages come from.
3. If my general understanding is correct, maybe someone could explain what am I doing wrong code-wise?

Comment: `open()` needs an open mode, like *read* or *write*.

Comment: I don't think you're doing the right thing. Why wrap a function into another function where all the original function can do exactly what you want.

Comment: m02ph3u5, as far as I understand, read is default mode, so it doesn't need to be specified. I've changed the code to "open(inputPath, mode='r', newline='')" and nothing have changed.

Comment: Anwarvic, I was thinking about using it like "ff = openFile(inputPath, delimiter=';')" only altering, say, delimiters as needed. For example I can feed a table into a function stating which delimiters it would need to use for each file. If I don't turn it into a function, I would need to write the whole code block "with open..." etc. every time. Basically, I try to be DRY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem (errors from `csv.reader()`) are because you need to use named parameters (not positional) for `delimiter` and `quotechar`.

The main problem is that you cannot `return` a file object.  Python closes the file object for you before returning.  (Thanks, Python!)

But I discovered that you can `yield` an open file object.  (See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825251/return-file-handles-opened-with-with-open)).

One more potential small problem I saw is that you are not passing your `newline` parameter to the `open()` - you are hard coding that to `''`.

Here is a fixed up and tested version of your program:

```py
import csv

def openFile(inputPath, newline='', delimiter=',', quotechar='"'):
    with open(inputPath, newline=newline) as csvfile:
        openedFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quotechar)
        yield openedFile

inputPath = "unit_structure.csv"
ff = openFile(inputPath, delimiter=';')

print(ff)

for g in ff:
    [ print(';'.join(r)) for r in g ]
```

With an input file `unit_structure.csv` containing this:

```
aaa;bbb;ccc
1;2;3
4;5;6
```

the program prints this:

```
<generator object openFile at 0x7f89771f3e60>
aaa;bbb;ccc
1;2;3
4;5;6
```

Comment: Thank you, you've answered all my questions. Yield is great, though I would like to emphasize for possible readers your suggestion to read further (esp. concerning one-time nature of generators).